# How can I make my countdown timer show hours

Tags: javascript, countdown

I'm looking for a quick change for a countdown timer a friend of mine once programmed. He currently can't help me change or extend it, so I'm looking for some help from the friendly folks of stackoverflow.

So far the countdown shows: 
**MM:SS:ss**

I want to change it to:
**HH:MM:SS**

An idea how I can achieve this? 
Many many thanks!

Here's my code:

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
var timer = duration, minutes, seconds, dispms;
const intervalIndex = setInterval(function () {
    dispms=parseInt(timer % 100,10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer / 100, 10);
    minutes = parseInt(seconds / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds % 60, 10);
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    dispms = dispms < 10 ? "0" + dispms : dispms;
    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if (--timer < 0) {
      clearInterval(intervalIndex);
    }
}, 10);}
window.onload = function () {
    var countdown = 60 * 60 * 100,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(countdown, display);
};
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
var timer = duration, minutes, seconds, dispms;
const intervalIndex = setInterval(function () {
    
    seconds = parseInt(timer / 100, 10);
    minutes = parseInt(seconds / 60, 10);
    hours = parseInt(minutes / 60, 10);
    
    seconds = parseInt(seconds % 60, 10);
    minutes = parseInt(minutes % 60, 10);
    
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
    
    display.textContent = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if (--timer < 0) {
      clearInterval(intervalIndex);
    }
}, 10);}
window.onload = function () {
    var countdown = 600500,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(countdown, display);
};
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!